# SearchView to perform search inside same activity

Tags: android, searchview

I have a `searchView` in my `SearchActivity` and it creates an intent to launch a `SearchActivityResults` according to the documentation here: http://developer.android.com/training/search/setup.html

How do I need to go if I want my `SearchView` to trigger a search from within my activity, when the soft keyboard lower right button is pressed to trigger the search?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

you just need to get your searchView menu , use override onCreateOptionsMenu

```
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat
            .getActionView(mSearchMenuItem);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {


        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
            // do your search on change or save the last string in search
            return false;
        }
    });

    // you can get query  
    searchView.getQuery();
```